# Copy from Excel and pasting into Access results in rounding error

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access

I copy from MS Excel a calculated value with two decimals, shown in [excel pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywrap.png)

Marked column has value 5297,95

If I paste this into MS Access I get a rounding error. Pasted value becomes 5297,94.

Why this difference?

The access file is linked to a mssql db and columns are numeric (9,2)

If I paste as text, results are correct.

Comment: What is the *actual* value within the cell? How are you inserting the value? I bet that the value is actually less than `5297.95` and greater than or equal to `5297.945` (for example`5297.9471`) and when you `INSERT` the value you are truncating it like a string value, rather than rounding it (up).

Comment: It's hard to believe a calculated column is truncated at 2 decimals, most likely, it contains more decimals but doesn't display these. Also note, Access uses banker's rounding, so would round 5297,945 to 5297,94, while Excel doesn't, and rounds 5297,945 to 5297,95. This could explain differences in rounding even if there's no truncation.

Comment: actual value in Excel is 5297,94520547945

Answer (score 0):

Please update your formula in your excel to use the `ROUND` formula:

if your cell is calculated as for example `=B2/2`

```
= ROUND(B2/2,2)
```

The last parameter is the number of digits you want to round to after the decimal sign, in your case the comma ",".

See this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/round-function-c018c5d8-40fb-4053-90b1-b3e7f61a213c) for the documentation on the round formula.

After that try your copy process again.